# Wix Toolset - Conditional installation based on TargetDir

Tags: installation, wix, conditional-statements

I have to install an application with several folders. If my Targetdir is not a default path, say `[ProgramFilesFolder]\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]`, all the folders can be installed in that Targetdir. Otherwise, some folders, say "Bin" and "AddIns", should be installed in a different path, say `[CommonAppDataFolder]\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]`.

I would like to avoid a C# or C++ custom action. Instead, I would try to use something like a Type51 CA. Is it possible?

I wrote the following code:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
    <Directory Id="dir_B1AA3D43_E9A6_4283_81B7_D24FDA02FEC4" Name="List SpA">
      <Component Id="comp_dir_B1AA3D43_E9A6_4283_81B7_D24FDA02FEC4" Guid="AB641867-3F7A-4A74-9923-03E71FC6851C" KeyPath="yes" Transitive="yes">
        <Condition><![CDATA[TARGETDIR = "[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]"]]></Condition>
      </Component>
      <Directory Id="dir_9D19AF5A_89F2_498D_AC25_B48F2C16BFF5" Name="TestApplication">
        <Directory Id="dir_BinID2" Name="Bin">
          <Component Id="comp_dir_BinID2" Guid="2E369F78-D321-4828-A2A8-E958E57B910B" KeyPath="yes">
            <Condition><![CDATA[TARGETDIR = "[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]"]]></Condition>
          </Component>
          <Component Id="comp_38B4C656_8291_4C45_98D5_A46908E33723" Guid="61DB01E5-6D6B-48AE-862A-3E2C18D546E7" Permanent="no" SharedDllRefCount="no" Transitive="no">
            <File Id="_14E547A6_A0C5_441E_A294_59AD578B99DF" DiskId="1" Hidden="no" ReadOnly="no" TrueType="no" System="no" Vital="yes" Name="TestApplication.exe" Source="..\Debug\TestApplication.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
          </Component>
        </Directory>
        <Directory Id="dir_AddInsID2" Name="AddIns">
          <Component Id="comp_dir_AddInsID2" Guid="0CA9B394-77E5-48A9-85A8-F6FF0737C499" KeyPath="yes" Transitive="yes">
            <Condition><![CDATA[TARGETDIR = "[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]"]]></Condition>
          </Component>
          <Component Id="comp_6DCECE0A_AE42_49F1_BA42_B23EF2A50E44" Guid="216B87DA-4F28-4DC9-85AA-E3801E2C0A8B" Permanent="no" SharedDllRefCount="no" Transitive="no">
            <File Id="_D271147D_4984_4C55_9660_33F4617957F5" DiskId="1" Hidden="no" ReadOnly="no" TrueType="no" System="no" Vital="yes" Name="ClosePromptCA.CA.dll" Source="..\ClosePromptCA\bin\Debug\ClosePromptCA.CA.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="comp_98FCDB58_9307_44D7_9CFE_3F1DB41BD779" Guid="B8368238-B1B6-4D78-BC21-0D26B84E4938" Permanent="no" SharedDllRefCount="no" Transitive="no">
            <File Id="_75368244_3285_47FD_BBC8_60CEC98755B4" DiskId="1" Hidden="no" ReadOnly="no" TrueType="no" System="no" Vital="yes" Name="Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll" Source="..\ClosePromptCA\bin\Debug\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="dir_AddInsID" Name="AddIns">
    <Component Id="comp_dir_AddInsID" Guid="0219CA84-4787-4737-99E7-95ACD8E0846D" KeyPath="yes" Transitive="yes">
      <Condition><![CDATA[TARGETDIR <> "[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]"]]></Condition>
    </Component>
    <Component Id="comp_23612F37_B27B_49E2_9FB6_9D2FA3654FB1" Guid="290915D5-38E9-4540-B7B7-7BBC27D96CA0" Permanent="no" SharedDllRefCount="no" Transitive="no">
      <File Id="_0193CC70_4486_4226_BE10_4F9C927DD5F2" DiskId="1" Hidden="no" ReadOnly="no" TrueType="no" System="no" Vital="yes" Name="ClosePromptCA.CA.dll" Source="..\ClosePromptCA\bin\Debug\ClosePromptCA.CA.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
    <Component Id="comp_41AA7508_C12C_46CC_A383_7088A8500898" Guid="5CACA050-A59C-44DF-BF5A-8694D547D937" Permanent="no" SharedDllRefCount="no" Transitive="no">
      <File Id="_362C000D_A631_4E5D_9288_FB623CD999E3" DiskId="1" Hidden="no" ReadOnly="no" TrueType="no" System="no" Vital="yes" Name="ClosePromptCA.XML" Source="..\ClosePromptCA\bin\Debug\ClosePromptCA.XML" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="dir_BinID" Name="Bin">
    <Component Id="comp_dir_BinID" Guid="99ADE113-162C-4299-8A3E-EDCE1FB838DE" KeyPath="yes" Transitive="yes">
      <Condition><![CDATA[TARGETDIR <> "[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]"]]></Condition>
    </Component>
    <Component Id="comp_FD9AB046_9110_4BFD_865F_D919F02D7B2B" Guid="5690A672-809F-47D1-938E-EAC0E18A0685" Permanent="no" SharedDllRefCount="no" Transitive="no">
      <File Id="_89CFA2F5_2ED8_43C8_890E_A791BF9E16BB" DiskId="1" Hidden="no" ReadOnly="no" TrueType="no" System="no" Vital="yes" Name="TestApplication.exe" Source="..\Debug\TestApplication.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="dir_DocsID" Name="Docs">
    <Component Id="comp_ECF1F68E_B9B8_49DD_9631_88E0722F8FCC" Guid="CB3861D1-6101-4F3C-94DD-AEE3EE74C217" Permanent="no" SharedDllRefCount="no" Transitive="no">
      <File Id="_9CE2FA29_27F8_4C00_B22D_A99AA59E5B2D" DiskId="1" Hidden="no" ReadOnly="no" TrueType="no" System="no" Vital="yes" Name="ReadMe.txt" Source="..\TestApplication\ReadMe.txt" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="dir_LogsID" Name="Logs">
    <Component Id="comp_B81BDCFD_B947_49C0_A07F_C1546D02E7AF" Guid="CE5206CE-E651-42C6-88AF-B7D83A9318C2" Permanent="no" SharedDllRefCount="no" Transitive="no">
      <File Id="_FF44C1E7_C235_47B9_BA01_C797D13EBA7D" DiskId="1" Hidden="no" ReadOnly="no" TrueType="no" System="no" Vital="yes" Name="trace.log" Source="bin\Debug\trace.log" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="dir_TemplateID" Name="Template">
    <Component Id="comp_8F946A00_3D1E_44C5_A288_E0662FFE253D" Guid="8C0A501B-15D4-46B1-91C3-23E5035CB145" Permanent="no" SharedDllRefCount="no" Transitive="no">
      <File Id="_39F2BD37_C7FE_4CF1_98C7_1E7BFC1B4873" DiskId="1" Hidden="no" ReadOnly="no" TrueType="no" System="no" Vital="yes" Name="ReadMe.txt" Source="..\..\CrashReportManager\ReadMe.txt" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Everything looks like right, but Wix ignore the Conditions. Wix installs my components even if the conditions are false! 
What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically harvest the both locations and set each location to different directory path.

Heat - http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/task_reference/heatdirectory.html

Directory flag is the harvesting directory.
DirectoryRefId is where to deploy on target machine.

This is the most common way to do that.

Comment: I never heard about Directory Harvesting, so I don't know how to use it.  Could you write an example, please?

Comment: Try this example - http://chriseelmaa.com/harvesting-files-with-wix-heat/

Answer (score 0):

You can address the special folder by using its special folders ID, a list of possible IDs can be found at msdn "[System Folder Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa370905%28VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#system_folder_properties)".

The following code sample will show you how the directory structure for your case could look like:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
<Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="MyProgramFilesFolder" Name="Manufacturer">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="InstallLocation">
            <!-- Your "all the folders can be installed in that Targetdir"
            can be inserted here -->
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
<Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFileFolder" Name="Manufacturer">
        <!--Your " 'Bin' and 'AddIns' Folders"-->
        <Directory Id="AddinFolder" Name="AddIns">
            <Component Id="YourFile" Guid="{SOME GUID}">
                <!-- Just a file below your folder -->
                <File Id="YourFile"
                      Name="FileName"
                      Source="Source of the file"/>
            </Component>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

The Code above could be used without a condition.

If you really like to install them to different folders based on Conditions, You need to duplicate your Components.
Here is a sample [Condition](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/getting-started/conditional-installation/) below one of the Components:

```
<Component Id="YourFile" Guid="{SOME GUID}">
    <Condition>YourCondition</Condition>
    <!-- Just a file below your folder -->
    <File Id="YourFile"
          Name="FileName"
          Source="Source of the file"/>
</Component>
```

Comment: What condition have I to put some  in AddIn and Bin Directories? I tried with `<Condition><![CDATA[TARGETDIR <> "[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]"]]></Condition>`, but Wix looks like just to ignore it. Why?

Comment: You do not need a condition to put some in the AddIn and Bin Directories, just add components with the stuff you like to add there. If you only have empty folders you need to say create directories (you can use "CreateFolder" under a Component to do this), if there are components in it, the folder will be created automatically. For structural reasons in you wxs-file you can also reference the directories by their Id. I will add an example component to the code sample above.

Comment: Your condition statement looks ok to me. To use the condition you have to add your structure twice (below TargetDir and below CommonAppDataFolder) by using your condition. - I recommend not to use the condition and always put your "AddIns" and "Bin" folders related stuff into the same location, independent of changes on the TargetDir.

Comment: am sorry, but I can't understand how to use my condition, and where to put it. Could you write some additional code, please?

Comment: You simply add a condition below a component. I've added a sample for a condition in my answer.

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestion, but Wix simply ignores my conditions. It installs my components even if the condition is false! What is the reason?  I also edited my question with the full code

Comment: I have suggested to not use the condition at all, because of the doubled entries needed to install your files to different folders depending on the result of the condition.
Looking at your code, I have to say, that you need to use the condition on all the Components, where you expect to have them installed under that condition.
I did not check if your condition statement evaluates to the correct values at the moment they will be checked. As I said "looks ok to me" I meant that the condition may be correct, but I am not sure if you can use it like that.